# ConcatMap skip the element if the request failed

Tags: angular, rxjs6

How to skip the element if the request get's failed in concatMap

```
const obs = from(this.genes);
this.subs = obs.pipe(
    concatMap(res => {
        const gn = this.service.getData(this.resource + '/' + res.name);
        return gn.pipe(map(r => {
            for (let x = 0; x < res.l; x++) {
                this.tableData[res.i + x]['g'] = r.gene;
            }
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        }));
    })
).subscribe(x => {}
);
```

Following is my data

```
[
        {
            "name": "tim",
            "i": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "keratin",
            "i": 1
        }...
```

If the first URL gets failed this is not going for the next url. How to skip it?

Answer (score 0):

`concatMap()` only affects "successful" emissions from the source observable ("`next()` handler called"). Furthermore for "skipping" values you could just not define the handler for them.

I would do either one of these two:

```
this.subs = obs
    .pipe(
        concatMap(res => this.service.getData(this.resource + '/' + res.name),
            // result selector to make both variables avaiable in subscribe 
            (outer, inner) => ({ res: outer, data: inner }))
    )
    .subscribe({
        next: (response => {
            for (let x = 0; x < response.res.l; x++) {
                this.tableData[response.res.i + x]['g'] = response.data.gene;
            }
        }),
        error: err => console.error(err)
    })
```

OR

```
this.subs = obs
    .pipe(
        concatMap(res => {
            return this.service.getData(this.resource + '/' + res.name)
                .pipe(
                    tap(r => {
                        for (let x = 0; x < res.l; x++) {
                            this.tableData[res.i + x]['g'] = r.gene;
                        }
                    })
                )
        })
    )
    .subscribe({
        next: response => { },
        error: err => console.error(err)
    })
```